# Wordpress Logo Editing

Tags: css, wordpress, graphical-logo

Client wants logo to be font and not an image.  The issue that the logo has 2 different colors and 2 different fonts.

For example the first word is !mpact and they are using the Impact font.  THe ! is in a red color and the mpact is in a white color.  The second word of the logo is in arial font.

I can use the css to edit the .logo class to be all Impact font and one color but how can I achieve all they are asking.

Here is my current code.

```
.logo {
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 28px;
}
```

Comment: Do you know php so i will post my Answer related to your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use span tags to do such a thing

remove what you had before and put this in:

```
<!-- [ wrapper ] start -->
    <style type="text/css">    

          #first {
                color:red;
          }

          #second {
                color:white;
          }

          #third {
                font-family:arial;
          }

          .logo {
            font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 28px;
          }

          </style>
<div class="wrapper">
            <span id="first">!</span><span id="second">mpact</span> <span id="third">(second
            word)</span>
</div>
<!-- [ wrapper ] end -->
```

Be sure to replace the "(second word)" with your second word

Comment: Thanks so much for helping!  I understand the span aspect but how do edit the div in wordpress?  The code is

    <!-- [ wrapper ] start -->
    <div class="wrapper">
    
     <a class="logo" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"></a>
    
     <?php get_search_form(); ?> 
    
    </div>
    <!-- [ wrapper ] end -->

Comment: your logo is in a php file you have to remove the php code and put this in, (see the edited post)

Comment: you have to remove `<!-- [ wrapper ] start --> <div class="wrapper"> <a class="logo" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"></a> <?php get_search_form(); ?> </div> <!-- [ wrapper ] end -->`

and replace it with the code above

Comment: Did not work. Is there anyway I can email you the login and files so you can take a look?

Comment: sure, contact me at gr8_boi52@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working answer

```
<style type="text/css">    
      #first {
            color:red;
      }

      #second {
            color:white;
      }

      #third {
            color:red;
            font-size:14px;
      }

      .logo {
        font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 38px;
      }

      body {
background-color: #071425;
}
</style>

<div class="logo">
   <span id="first">!</span><span id="second">mpact</span><br /><span id="third">Advisory Group LLC</span>
</div>
```